# What is the use of $:$ other than "such that"?

Tags: notation

Take this way of writing the Axiom of Pairing in the ZFC axioms, for example:

${\forall}A:{\forall}B:{\exists}x:{\forall}y:(y\,{\in}\,x{\iff}y=A\,∨ \,y=B)$

Clearly $:$ doesn't mean "such that" here. What does it mean then?

Comment: It is just used as a spacer between quantifiers, nothing more.

Comment: Why isn't there another symbol, e.g. a comma, used for that?

Comment: Mathematical notation is like sausage making and politics. Best not to ask too many questions.

Comment: The colon is idiosyncratic here.

Comment: Also what's the purpose of writing ${\forall}B:{\exists}x$ instead of ${\forall}B{\exists}x$?

Comment: The purpose is readability.

Comment: "What is the purpose of writing $\forall B: \exists x$ instead of  $\forall B \exists x$?" -- none, other to serve as a noisy separator. Uses space "\," to separate the quantifiers: compare $\forall B\, \exists x\, \phi(B,x)$ [with space] to $\forall B \exists x \phi(B,x)$ [without].

Comment: So ${\forall}B\,{\exists}x$ is technically correct and colon is used only for aesthetical purposes?

Comment: That's right. In fact, using ":" in this way isn't really "technically correct" — I don't know a single presentation of first order logic that incorporates it as an official element of the syntax. It doesn't help resolve ambiguity, as parentheses do; it's just noise, which some consider pleasant by analogy with the separator of "set builder" notation. However, although you can pronounce it "such that" after $\exists v$, you can't pronounce it that way after a universal quantifier, as nobody says that.

Comment: Also, is there any difference between $({\forall}A{\forall}B){\exists}x$ and ${\forall}A{\forall}B{\exists}x$?